# remove rows which are not aligned with any of the column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe where I have four columns but at the same time I see the Index position `8` which is not aligned with any of the dataframe column, Is there a way to remove it based on some condition?

However, I can remove it with `df.iloc[:-1]` as I know its last row in the dataframe, but looking for some conditional checks if there are multiple such columns.

```
                    Locations    Cases Deaths Recovered
0               United States  1104149  63982    132941
1                       Spain   215216  24824    114678
2                       Italy   205463  27967     75945
3              United Kingdom   177454  27510         —
4                     Germany   163432   6637    117734
5                      France   129581  24376     49476
8  As of 1 May 2020 (UTC) · History of cases: Chi...  As of 1 May 2020 (UTC) · History of cases: Chi...  As of 1 May 2020 (UTC) · History of cases: Chi...  As of 1 May 2020 (UTC) · History of cases: Chi...
```

Comment: You've checked to make sure that it's not a part of any column in row 8?

Comment: Yes, I'm damn sure about it, it's just a line printed at the end, it is parsed from html page.

Comment: What happens to that line if you try to create a new column? For example: ```df['test'] = df['Locations'].apply(lambda x: x+"_test")```?

Comment: nothing happens except it creates addition column test with `_`  `Location` names such as `United States_test` and those lines at the end remains same.

Comment: is Location always a country? if yes you can test with `countries=[i.name for i in pycountry.countries]` and `df[df['Locations'].isin(countries)]`

Comment: @anky, yes that's true,  i'm parsing the data from [url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic_data)  which may give you some idea which is a html table.

Comment: Where `pycountry` is defined?

Comment: You have to install and import the same.

Comment: Okay but again it does not print the names like white space and special chars like `Saint Pierre & Miquelon`

Comment: For now,  I'm using map  function to map the length of column values and printing only if its less than 50 , beacuse i know country names are falling under the length of 50,  `print(df[df['Locations'].map(len) < 50])` or `print(df[df['Locations'].map(len).lt(50)])`  and  `print(df[df['Locations'].str.len().lt(50)])`